# Wait for specific text in DOM element before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that should wait for some text to change before it returns a value:

```
function getElementText() {
   while(isLoading()) {
   }
   return $('#element').text();
}

function isLoading() {
    return  $('#element')[0] &&
            $('#element').text().indexOf('Loading') >= 0;
}
```

However I think the empty `while` is not a good option (will it block the event loop?)

Comment: rx.js observable is your best friend. or EventEmitter

Comment: I think yes. The while loop will freeze the page. You can use setInterval to check if the text has changed.

Comment: Couldn't you put a listener on that element's change event and then call your `getElementText` as a callback with the value when it meets your conditions?

Answer (score 2):

No need of jQuery or any other external library, you can simply use MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Here a simple example, you will have a notice of type `characterData` when your text changes (after 5 seconds in my example):

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('some-id');
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, attributes: true, subtree: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
 
// later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();
setTimeout(function() {
 target.innerText = 'Changed text!';
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="some-id">
  AAA
</div>
```

Remove from the config of the observer all the properties you don't need to spy for changes

Answer (score 1):

Elegant way with rxjs:

```js
var source = document.getElementById('source');
var target = document.getElementById('target');

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(source, 'keyup')
  .filter( (e) => e.target.value === 'Admin' )
  .subscribe( () => target.innerText = "Matched." );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.min.js"></script>

<input id="source" /> <strong>input 'Admin' to trigger</strong>
<p id="target">Not match.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMSubtreeModified` event will be triggered when a change occurs in the element, so you can use that to detect if the text is loaded.

You can use a callback function to return the value when it has loaded. Or even better: (jQuery) promises!

```js
var element = document.getElementById('element');

function isLoading() {
    return element.innerText.indexOf('Loading') >= 0;
}

function getElementText() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    if (!isLoading()) {
        def.resolve(element.innerText);
        return def.promise();
    }

    $(element).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        if (!isLoading()) {
            def.resolve(element.innerText);
        }
    });

    return def.promise();
}

getElementText().then(function (text) {
    // Text is loaded!
    alert(text);
});

// Load text after 3 seconds for demonstration
setTimeout(function () {
    element.innerText = 'Changed!';
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element">Loading</div>
```